# Is there a difference between $\mathbb R^\infty$, $\mathbb{R^N}$, and $\mathbb R^\omega$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I've seen these three notations and I'd like to know the difference:

- $\mathbb{R}^\infty$
- $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$
- $\mathbb{R}^\omega$

Comment: If you enclose them in dollar signs you get nice formatting.  infty takes a backslash as well to get $\mathbb{R}^\infty$

Comment: Yes, they all mean the same thing (they are certainly isomorphic).

Comment: Some of these notations occasionally suggest notions of order or other structure beyond the set itself. With particular examples of who is defining these objects and for what purpose it might be easier to potentially differentiate between them. I can imagine a world in which they are all the same.

Comment: I have seen the claim that one can find in the same unnamed text, presumably on different pages $$\\ \omega=\aleph_0\\|2^\omega|=|\omega|\\|2^{\aleph_0}| \gt \aleph_0$$

Comment: @RossMillikan: Look up typing and implicit type-coercion.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ are almost always synonyms, and both refer to the set of functions $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ (aka sequences of real numbers indexed by $\mathbb{N}$).  The symbol $\omega$ is an alternate name for the set of natural numbers (or more specifically, for one particular set-theoretic construction of the natural numbers) which is commonly used in set theory.  Conceivably someone might distinguish $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ as, for instance, $\omega$ is always taken to include $0$ but some authors exclude $0$ from $\mathbb{N}$.  I've never seen anyone actually intentionally make such a distinction, though.

$\mathbb{R}^\infty$ is sometimes a synonym for $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, but sometimes it instead refers to the subset of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ consisting of those functions $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ that are $0$ on all but finitely many inputs.

Comment: Just as we say the vector $(a,b)\in \mathbb R^2$ is a vector in 2D space and similarly for higher dimensions (finite). Using this analogy, $\mathbb R^\infty$ will have vectors with infinitely many elements for example the set $\{\sin x: x\in \mathbb R\}\in \mathbb R^\infty $. Can $\mathbb R^\infty$ be explained like this?

Answer (score -2):

Hints : A basic open set of $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ is of the form
$$
U = U_1\times U_2\times \cdots \times U_n \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \cdots
$$
where $U_i$ are open sets in $\mathbb{R}$

similarly  for $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ and  $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$